# Graphml parse error : Invalid xmlChar

Tags: python, igraph, graphml

igraph version : 0.6.5
python version : 2.7.6

I am calculating the Betweenness centrality on a graphml graph dump. But while reading through the **Read_GraphML** function it throws the following error :

```
egraph = Graph.Read_GraphML("/path/graph.graphml")
igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at foreign-graphml.c:1042: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 55349, Parse error
```

XML namespance seems correct

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.1/graphml.xsd">
```

Could anyone suggest what could be the problem ? Is it with the graphml?

Comment: What is the actual character? and how was the file created?

Comment: Rexster, Gremlin console using command : g.saveGraphML('graph.graphml')    [Link](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/)

Comment: I am pretty sure that the GraphML file is not valid. Run it through an XML validator to see whether it reveals any errors.

Comment: The GraphML is around 8-10 GB's. Are their any specified algorithms that I could use to validate it ?